# Power BI embedded Paginated Report - are Read permissions necessary?

Tags: powerbi

I created a standard report in PBI Desktop and paginated report in Report Builder, both using the same source dataset, then I embedded the paginated report in the standard report.
After publishing it into PBI Service and viewing it directly in the workspace, it renders correctly (both the standard and the paginated part within display ok).

The issue starts when I want to distribute this report via an app. Steps taken:

1. Creating the app - adding this report as the content
2. Adding test users as viewers of this app

For the viewer, only the standard reports displays ok, the paginated report within in doesnt - there is a grey field with "Can't display the visual" error message in it.
Therefore I check the permissions on the underlying dataset - they are the App type, as expected. However, this seems to be not enough for the embedded paginated report.

When I add Read rights on the paginated report and update the app, the viewer sees the embedded paginated report correctly. However this means they are able to get to the paginated report directly via Shared with me, and not via the standard report (in the app), where this paginated report is embedded.

Do I always need to manually add the Read rights to a paginated report if I want to embed it in a standard report?

Any advice is much appreciated
Thank you